# Only one sprite on the scene at once Cocos2D 3.x

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

The sprite appears every time the screen is touched, then it shoots to the desired area. How would i make it that only one sprite will be on the scene at a time until it exits the scene or hits an object? (even though the screen is touched multiple times)

This is the projectile code

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
// 1
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

// 2
CGPoint offset    = ccpSub(touchLocation, _player.position);
float   ratio     = offset.y/offset.x;
int     targetX   = _player.contentSize.width/2 + self.contentSize.width;
int     targetY   = (targetX*ratio) + _player.position.y;
CGPoint targetPosition = ccp(targetX,targetY);

// 3
CCSprite *projectile = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"projectile.png"];
projectile.position = _player.position;
projectile.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:projectile.contentSize.width/2.0f andCenter:projectile.anchorPointInPoints];
projectile.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"playerGroup";
projectile.physicsBody.collisionType  = @"projectileCollision";
[_physicsWorld addChild:projectile];

// 4
CCActionMoveTo *actionMove   = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5f position:targetPosition];
CCActionRemove *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
[projectile runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove,actionRemove]]];

[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:@"pew-pew-lei.caf"];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your point correctly , you could simply add a flag , to be able to notice when there's already a sprite on the scene. Just declare on your class a

```
BOOL isSpritePresent;
```

Initialize it on your class custom id method.

```
-(id)init {
self=[super init];
isSpritePresent=NO;
return self; }
```

And then on the start of TouchBegan add something like

```
if(isSpritePresent){
return; //As there's already an sprite on the scene.
}
```

And at the end

```
isSpritePresent=YES;
```

And finally when the arrow or w/e it is reached its target , call a method to reset the Boolean.

Or... If you're looking forward to doing things simpler and you believe you have an specific time to let the user shoot again just add a delay after the other actions as ..

```
CCActionDelay *delay = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:1.2f];
        [projectile runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove,actionRemove,delay]]];
```

Comment: How would i initialize it into the class?
I'm new, sorry if its a stupid question. Thank you :)

Comment: If you're making your own class you could start with the small piece of code I updated up here, if you're using another class as your parent node well might depend on the init they will need, you'll need to override it . Or if the class has already an init method well simply define the value of isSpritePresent=NO over there.